# Do PS4 games have online playing codes?

Tags: psn, ps4

I'm considering buying a PS4 and have a question about online multiplayer games. Some PS3 games had codes for online play that allows to link to only one account. Do PS4 games have such codes as well? Specifically I want to know about Fifa 15, Battlefield 4 and GTA V games. I want to buy used games, but I also want to be able to play online.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the online passes you are referring to have been [discontinued](http://help.ea.com/uk/article/online-pass-has-been-discontinued/) [in 2013](http://www.ign.com/articles/2013/11/01/ubisoft-kills-online-pass-system-effective-immediately) and the existing online passes were made available for free on the Playstation Store. Sony doesn't seem to have plans to re-introduce them, as the software product development head for Sony Worldwide Studios America Scott Rohde [said before the console release in 2013](http://www.gamasutra.com/view/news/194150/Further_clarification_on_Sonys_DRM_policies_No_more_online_pass.php):

> "It's just like it always was, is the easiest way to say it. Better, in fact, because online pass, in the future we're going away from that."

You will, however, need a Playstation Plus subscription to play online with the PS4, but there are no restrictions for used games.